# Getting Visual Studio to correctly debug a hybrid Java/C++ app on an Android phone

Tags: android, c++, visual-studio-2022

Ok, the problem is easily stated. I want to debug the C++ portion of code that is written in a mix of Java and C++ on an actual phone (as opposed to an emulator) running Android version 13 through Visual Studio 2022. The phone is in developer mode, is attached by USB cable, and permanently trusts the PC. The C++ code is written for Visual Studio and cannot be debugged through Android Studio.

I have set breakpoints in the C++ code only, and have set Visual Studio to debug the ARM64 version of the app.

Visual Studio is correctly identifying the phone and does initiate something on the device. However, the device is showing a message that it is waiting for the debugger to attach. I am then attaching Visual Studio to the adb process, since I think that's the debugger.

Visual Studio attaches to something, since it is off and running, but the phone is still saying it is waiting for the debugger.

If I then try from the other direction - start the app on the phone and attach Visual Studio to the process - then Visual Studio will say "Error while trying to enter break state. Debugging will now stop. Failed to find thread 71 for break event."

If I hit cancel on the Android device after Visual Studio finishes starting up its side, then Visual Studio will report "Failed to connect to and resume the Android Java Virtual Machine. This may be because a Java debugger, such as Eclipse, is already connected. Resume the Java debugger or close it." This message is the same whether or not I've attached to adb.

I was expecting one of these two approaches to correctly start the app, link up with Visual Studio, and permit me to debug the C++ portion of the code through breakpoints as I would any other C++ application.

The code all works, but I need to be able to see what's going on in the C++ portions and not just the Java code.

I've checked the version of Android that is being built for and it matches the version on the phone. I'm completely out of idea for how to do this.

Comment: What's stopping you from using Android Studio to debug C++? It's meant to debug Android, after all.

Comment: The application is built in Visual Studio and uses only Visual Studio build files. Android Studio only seems to recognize C++ built using ndk-build or CMake, neither of which is the case here. (Unfortunately, this is legacy software I'm maintaining, so I don't get to change the build system.)

Comment: I have since been asked to move over to CMake. I've done this, and Android Studio happily compiles the C++ code but doesn't like doing a symbolic debug. Trying to identify why. I've posted the CMakeFile.txt in another question, if you want to have a crack at helping me with CMake stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the solution is one of those "that's strange!" moments. Visual Studio has to compile to the MINIMUM supported API supported by the Java side in Android Studio, or the whole thing blows up. I also discovered that I can't have both Android Studio and Visual Studio simultaneously running, even if they're not doing anything. It causes the debugger in Visual Studio to jam up.

I don't know if this is unique to this software, or if it's a common issue with trying to couple Android Studio and Visual Studio.